# Deleting node from a singly linked list (except for the tail)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to programming and I'm trying to understand the following code:

```
    # class ListNode(object):
    #     def __init__(self, x):
    #         self.val = x
    #         self.next = None

    class Solution(object):
        def deleteNode(self, node):
            node.val = node.next.val
            node.next = node.next.next
```

My intuition for the code is the following: 
I understand that node is a reference to an element in the linked list and node.next is a pointer to the next node. I also understand that node.val sets the value of the current node to the value of the next node. What exactly is the purpose of

```
    node.next = node.next.next?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the following linked list nodes (where n2 is the node you're removing)

```
... -> n1 -> n2 -> n3 -> ...
 node -^     ^     ^- node.next.next
             |
     node.next
```

So if you set `node.next = node.next.next` you get this:

```
             n2
             |
             v
... -> n1 -> n3 -> ...
 node -^     ^     
             |      
     node.next
```

And since now nothing is referring to n2 once the function returns it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you

Comment: So for the case of the tail in the linked list, this wouldn't work because when the node is the tail, node.next would be None, right?

Comment: If the `node.next` (the node we're deleting) is the tail, then `node.next.next` is `None`, but the logic above is fine because then `node.next` will be set to `None` and `node` will be the new tail

Comment: That being said, I'm not sure why you're moving the `node.val` around. You shouldn't need to do that.

Answer (score 2):

NodeA -> NodeB -> NodeC

So currently NodeA.next is NodeB

by assinging NodeA.next = NodeA.next.next we get NodeA.next = NodeB.next which makes

NodeA.next = NodeC

so the chain is now

NodeA -> NodeC

Answer (score 1):

It means that the link to next node is removed and this node links to next.next node , it means the next node is deleted and its value replace with this node value.
for example we have following list:

```
1->2->3->4
1.next(2) = 1.next.next(3)
```

so list updatedt to:

```
1->3->4
```

Comment: @RogerJosh when you use 1.next its the link to 2 when you change it to 3 the link to 2 is removing

Comment: Thank you so much, Arman. Just one last question. I understand that the 1's next would now be 3, but wouldn't there also be a link from 2 to 3 still? How does 2 get garbage collected?

Comment: @RogerJosh the link between 2 and 3 is not important now , cause 2 is now deleted and when you trace throw nodes you never reach 2 node

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense